# create data frame from file

Tags: python, dataframe

can we create a data frame for the below input:

```
OP1.T1:OP2.V2
OP1.T1:OP2.V3
OP2.T3:OP2.V2
OP3.T1:OP1.V2
```

Code tried:

```
with open("TableView.txt") as f:
   
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        #print(line)
        cols = line.split(':')
        my_params = (cols[0],cols[1])
        #print(my_params)
        df= pd.DataFrame(my_params)
        print(df)
```

i need them likebelow:

```
    BaseS   BASET   DEPS    DEPN
0   OP1     T1      OP2    v2
1   OP1     T1      OP2    v3
2   OP2     T3      OP2    v2
3   OP3     T1      OP1   v2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.read_csv`, you can specify `\.|:` as separator, which separates on either `.` or `:`:

```
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO('''OP1.T1:OP2.V2
OP1.T1:OP2.V3
OP2.T3:OP2.V2
OP3.T1:OP1.V2''')

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep='\.|:', header=None, names=['BaseS', 'BaseT', 'DEPS', 'DEPN'])

df

  BaseS BaseT DEPS DEPN
0   OP1    T1  OP2   V2
1   OP1    T1  OP2   V3
2   OP2    T3  OP2   V2
3   OP3    T1  OP1   V2
```

Comment: Very clever – I didn't realize `sep` took multiple values.

Comment: @ybressler_simon Yeah `sep` can take both [literal delimiter and regex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: <ipython-input-17-73141a771c37>:7: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\.|:', header=None, names=['BaseS', 'BaseT', 'DEPS', 'DEPN']), i get this error

Comment: It's a warning not an error. To get rid of the warning you can add `engine='python'` to the call

Comment: yeah. got it. thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: any reason why it ignores my first row of data?

Comment: Not really sure. Is the first row corrupted or you had skipped some lines ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237586/discussion-between-rose-and-psidom).